# OpenTelemetry and Angular

Tags: angular, open-telemetry

Trying to implement OpenTelemetry with an Angular Frontend App.

I've followed this guide: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/adding-opentelemetry-to-an-angular-application#sending-traces-with-processors-and-exporters

and was able to send my traces to console and to honeycomb **successfully**. (This uses @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web)

```
Code for that is here: 
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import {
    WebTracerProvider,
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
    SimpleSpanProcessor,
    BatchSpanProcessor,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http';
import { ZoneContextManager } from '@opentelemetry/context-zone';
import { trace } from 'console';
import { NodeTracerProvider, ConsoleSpanExporter,SimpleSpanProcessor,BatchSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';


const provider = new NodeTracerProvider();
//const provider = new WebTracerProvider();
 
// For demo purposes only, immediately log traces to the console
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
 
// Batch traces before sending them to HoneyComb
provider.addSpanProcessor(
    new BatchSpanProcessor(
        new OTLPTraceExporter({
            url: 'https://api.honeycomb.io/v1/traces',
            headers: {
                'x-honeycomb-team': '<redacted>',
            },
        }),
    ),
);
 
provider.register({
  contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
});
 
 
registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [
        getWebAutoInstrumentations({
            '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-document-load': {},
            '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-user-interaction': {},
            '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fetch': {},
            '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-xml-http-request': {},
        }),
    ],
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set it up with ZipKin/ Jaeger. Here's what I have now (taken from https://logz.io/blog/nodejs-javascript-opentelemetry-auto-instrumentation/#exam)

```
const {
    BasicTracerProvider,
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
    SimpleSpanProcessor,
} = require("@opentelemetry/tracing");
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http");
const { Resource } = require("@opentelemetry/resources");
const {
    SemanticResourceAttributes,
} = require("@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions");

const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const {
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations,
} = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");


const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: "http://localhost:4318/v1/traces"
});

const provider = new BasicTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]:
            "YOUR-SERVICE-NAME",
    }),
});
// export spans to console (useful for debugging)
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
// export spans to opentelemetry collector
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

provider.register();
const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
    traceExporter: exporter,
    instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});

sdk
    .start()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Tracing initialized");
    })
    .catch((error: any) => console.log("Error initializing tracing", error));
```

but that results in endless compilation errors.
Some like this:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
        - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
```

I resolved these by following the Angular section of this: https://web3auth.io/docs/troubleshooting/webpack-issues

After that I still have many errors like the following:

```
./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel-credentials.js:23:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channelz.js:23:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js:27:12-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/load-balancing-call.js:31:14-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js:23:12-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js:31:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-ip.js:22:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js:25:14-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js:23:14-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel-address.js:23:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel-call.js:23:14-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/tls-helpers.js:23:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/transport.js:23:14-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/transport.js:24:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/transport.js:32:12-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'

./node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/util.js:25:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@grpc\proto-loader\build\src'

./node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AsyncHooksContextManager.js:23:19-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@opentelemetry\context-async-hooks\build\src'

./node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.js:23:22-44 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@opentelemetry\context-async-hooks\build\src'

./node_modules/@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger/build/src/jaeger.js:25:16-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@opentelemetry\exporter-jaeger\build\src'

./node_modules/@opentelemetry/instrumentation-net/build/src/instrumentation.js:29:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@opentelemetry\instrumentation-net\build\src'

./node_modules/@opentelemetry/otlp-grpc-exporter-base/build/src/util.js:28:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@opentelemetry\otlp-grpc-exporter-base\build\src'

./node_modules/jaeger-client/dist/src/reporters/http_sender.js:34:10-23 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\jaeger-client\dist\src\reporters'

./node_modules/jaeger-client/dist/src/reporters/udp_sender.js:34:13-29 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\jaeger-client\dist\src\reporters'

./node_modules/jaeger-client/dist/src/reporters/udp_sender.js:36:10-23 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\jaeger-client\dist\src\reporters'

./node_modules/jaeger-client/dist/src/thrift.js:39:10-23 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\jaeger-client\dist\src'

./node_modules/thriftrw/thrift.js:26:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\thriftrw'
```

am I just going about this wrong? seems like only the sdk-trace-web works (not sdk-trace-node)

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think this has to be done with the fact that the javascript instrumentation is still mostly implemented for node.js applications and not for browser applications. I'm facing the same issue. That's why you get all the errors pointing to polyfills for node.js modules.

Comment: We are exactly at the same point as you are. With Angular 17 we are trying alternative builders now, which have been introduced besides Webpack